# LaTeX align minted code fragments

Tags: floats

I would like to align the first lines of the code and the captions in the following listings. This is my LaTeX code. I've also uploaded an image of the output.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{minted}{c++}
void MyClass::Run()
{
    // no work
    if (!m_HasWork) 
        return;

    /* process the new frame */

    // done
    m_HasWork = false;
}
  \end{minted}
  \captionof{listing}{Main thread (process a frame)}
  \label{fig:thread1}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{minted}{c++}
void MyClass::Update(
    const video::ImageFrame& Frame)
{
    // skip frame (not done with previous)
    if (m_HasWork)
        return;

    /* make a local copy 
     * of the frame */

   // indicate that there's work
    m_HasWork = true; 
}
  \end{minted}
  \captionof{listing}{Interrupt (get a frame)}
  \label{fig:interrupt}
 \end{minipage}
 \captionof{listing}{not relevant}
  \label{fig:sync}
\end{figure}
```

Output: (I want the captions of listings 1 and 2 on the same line)

[image: output]

Comment: After the first `\end{minipage}` you need a `%`. At the moment you get an unwanted space which results in the with `0.5\textwidth+0.5\textwidth+\space`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it manually with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{minted}{c++}
void MyClass::Run()
{
    // no work
    if (!m_HasWork) 
        return;

    /* process the new frame */

    // done
    m_HasWork = false;
}
  \end{minted}
  \vspace{2\baselineskip}
  \captionof{listing}{Main thread (process a frame)}
  \label{fig:thread1}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{minted}{c++}
void MyClass::Update(
    const video::ImageFrame& Frame)
{
    // skip frame (not done with previous)
    if (m_HasWork)
        return;

    /* make a local copy 
     * of the frame */

   // indicate that there's work
    m_HasWork = true; 
}
  \end{minted}
  \captionof{listing}{Interrupt (get a frame)}
  \label{fig:interrupt}
 \end{minipage}
 \captionof{listing}{not relevant}
  \label{fig:sync}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`\vspace{2\baselineskip}` adds the two lines missing between the first `minted` environment and its caption in order to align both captions.

Answer (score 1):

use the `[b]` option for `minipage` and indert a second dummy line for the second caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{minted}{c++}
void MyClass::Run()
{
    // no work
    if (!m_HasWork) 
        return;

    /* process the new frame */

    // done
    m_HasWork = false;
}
  \end{minted}
  \captionof{listing}{Main thread (process a frame)}
  \label{fig:thread1}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{minted}{c++}
void MyClass::Update(
    const video::ImageFrame& Frame)
{
    // skip frame (not done with previous)
    if (m_HasWork)
        return;

    /* make a local copy 
     * of the frame */

   // indicate that there's work
    m_HasWork = true; 
}
  \end{minted}
  \captionof{listing}{Interrupt (get a frame)\newline~ }
  \label{fig:interrupt}
 \end{minipage}
 \captionof{listing}{not relevant}\label{fig:sync}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]