# How to make a minted code listing centered on a page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, minted

So, I am writing a report with Prolog code listings in it. I have been using *lstlisting* to make my listings and I made my code centered on the page, such as this:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Listing}
\begin{figure}[thp]
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{c}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=Prolog]
somePredicate(A, B) :-
    arbitraryPredicate(A),
    anotherPredicate(B).
  \end{lstlisting}
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{My Prolog Predicate}
 \label{lst:firstListing}
\end{figure}
```

Generated output:

[image: First Listing]

It works very well. This is based on the following answer on stackexchange: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5822/46424

However, I want to switch to the *minted-package* to represent my code snippets, as it shows the code with nice colors. *This is where it goes wrong.* I got minted to work, but I cannot get my listing centered anymore.

After searching on the web I found only one question about aligning minted code: [LaTeX align minted code fragments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111034/latex-align-minted-code-fragments)

So, just as it shows there in the answers of that question, I tried to use a minipage. This, however, did not work as expected. The code is simply aligned left instead of centered if I write the following:

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Listing}
\begin{figure}[thp]
 \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
  \centering
  \begin{minted}{prolog}
somePredicate(A, B) :-
    arbitraryPredicate(A),
    anotherPredicate(B).
  \end{minted}
  \caption{My Prolog Predicate}
  \label{lst:firstListing}
 \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Generated output:

[image]

I have also tried to combine tabular with minted, but then pdflatex gets an error and no pdf-file gets generated.

So, my question is: *how do I make my code listings, that are represented by the minted-package, centered on my page?*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you want to switch to `minted`? There may be a way of configuring `listings` to get the highlighting you want. Try, for instance, `\lstdefinestyle{myPrologstyle}
{
  language=Prolog,
  basicstyle = \ttfamily\color{blue},
  moredelim = [s][\color{black}]{(}{)},
  literate = {:-}{{\textcolor{black}{:-}}}2
             {,}{{\textcolor{black}{,}}}1
             {.}{{\textcolor{black}{.}}}1
}`. I encourage you to post another question about how to customise `listings` to mimic the Pygments's Prolog lexer (used internally by `minted`).

Comment: @Jubobs If it can be done with listings instead of minted, then I am willing to stick to listings. Your suggestion is a good start for mimicking the Pygments's Prolog lexer, but there are still some differences.. for instance: the color blue is different, and you did not make the variables blue. Yes, maybe I will post another question then, but first I will see if egreg's and Herbert's answers work for me. Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: @Jubobs As you encouraged me to do, I posted another question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161235/how-do-i-customize-listings-to-mimic-the-highlighting-of-prolog-code-in-minted

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want *all* `minted` environments to be centered and you don't need the `Verbatim` environment (provided by `fancyvrb`) for other purposes, then

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\usepackage{minted}
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Listing}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{minted}{prolog}
somePredicate(A, B) :-
    arbitraryPredicate(A),
    anotherPredicate(B).
\end{minted}

\caption{My Prolog Predicate}
\label{lst:firstListing}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If, instead, you want to choose between centered and full width `minted` environments, define a `cminted` environment; the definition is a bit convoluted: we save a copy of `\minted` and modify it to issue the `\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment` command locally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch,letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\cminted}{\minted}
\let\endcminted\endminted
\xpretocmd{\cminted}{\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}}{}{}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Listing}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{cminted}{prolog}
somePredicate(A, B) :-
    arbitraryPredicate(A),
    anotherPredicate(B).
\end{cminted}

\caption{My Prolog Predicate}
\label{lst:firstListing}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I have not tried it, but I am sure it works perfectly. I have gone with Herbert's answer because it looks easier to use.. However, I am interested in why you would define a cminted environment instead of simply using a minipage. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @PJvG Because you *can't* know how wide you have to make the `minipage`, can you?

Comment: @PJvG Try making both methods with longer lines and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Umm no I do not know that. However, I use the following settings in my report: `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report} \usepackage[top=70pt,bottom=70pt,left=65pt,right=65pt]{geometry}`. My guess is that someone would know how wide the minipage needs to be, if he or she knows these settings. Is my assumption wrong here? Anyway, I can see now that your answer is more generic than Herbert's answer. As I think genericity is more important than simplicity, I am going to accept your answer now. Thanks.

Comment: @PJvG It doesn't depend on the global text width, but on the width of the particular listing. With Herbert's method you need to guess the width of the listing; if the guess is wrong by defect, the listing will stick out on the right, if by excess it will stick out on the left. With the `BVerbatim` you get centering without any guess.

Comment: Ah okay, it is clear to me now, thanks for that.

Comment: The `\renewcommand{\figurename}{Listing}` and using `figure` instead of `listing` part seems to be unnecessary? I seem to be able to directly use `listing` in this case just fine.

Comment: @XiangJi No, it is not necessary; it was in the OP's document, so I followed that setup.

Answer (score 5):

your minipage makes no sense. Use it this way:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[thp]
\centering 
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{minted}{prolog}
somePredicate(A, B) :-
    arbitraryPredicate(A),
    anotherPredicate(B).
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
\caption{My Prolog Predicate}\label{lst:firstListing}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks, it works. However, can you please elaborate why my minipage makes no sense? I do not have much experience with minipages, but I am willing to learn how they work. Also, I have accepted your answer for its simplicity.

Comment: I have changed my mind on which answer to accept. See the comments on egreg's answer for the reason why.

Answer (score 0):

@egreg's answer is great and inspired what I'm doing now...

```
\newminted[ccodefig]{c}{fontsize=\footnotesize,linenos}
\xpretocmd{\ccodefig}{\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}}{}{}
\xpretocmd{\ccodefig*}{\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}}{}{}
```

The first line creates a new minted environment called `ccodefig` (I read this as "c code [for use in] figure[s]"), but you can name it anything. It also creates `ccodefig*` which allows option overrides over the defaults that you set for this command.

Then I just do what egreg suggested to change the underlying implementation from `Verbatim` to `BVerbatim`.

I like that this lets me set defaults for a given language at the same time as I create the new command. Then I just patch it up for horizontal centering.