# Set minted colored background length

Tags: minted

Is there a way to modify the code that `minted` uses to draw the background to have it up to the middle of the page, or a custom length? 
I think it should be done with a `\newcommand` or something like that since I want to keep the default style for large pieces of code, and the customized background length for small pieces of code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle[c++]{manni}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codebackground}{RGB}{240, 240, 235}

\newlength{\msize}
\setlength{\msize}{\dimexpr(\paperwidth-\textwidth)/2\relax}

\begin{document} 
\hspace*{\msize} Stop background here?\par
\hspace*{\msize} $ \downarrow $
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=codebackground]{c} 
int main() {
  printf("hello, world");
  return 0;
}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Here is the code that `minted` uses, taken from [its documentation](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf)

```
\newenvironment{minted@colorbg}[1]{%
\setlength{\OuterFrameSep}{0pt}%
\colorlet{shadecolor}{#1}%
\let\minted@tmp\FV@NumberSep
\edef\FV@NumberSep{%
\the\numexpr\dimexpr\minted@tmp+\number\fboxsep\relax sp\relax}%
\medskip
\begin{snugshade*}}
{\end{snugshade*}%
\medskip\noindent}
```

Comment: You can put the `minted` environment in a minipage, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161126/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to box the `minted` environment, you can do

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usemintedstyle[c++]{manni}
\definecolor{codebackground}{RGB}{240, 240, 235}

\newsavebox{\mintedbox}
\newenvironment{boxminted}
 {%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mintedbox}
  \begin{minted}%
 }
 {%
  \end{minted}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \noindent\colorbox{codebackground}{\usebox{\mintedbox}}%
 }


\begin{document}

\begin{boxminted}{c}
int main() {
  printf("hello, world");
  return 0;
}
\end{boxminted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For a fixed size width,

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usemintedstyle[c++]{manni}
\definecolor{codebackground}{RGB}{240, 240, 235}

\newlength{\msize}
\setlength{\msize}{\dimexpr\textwidth/2\relax}

\newsavebox{\mintedbox}
\newenvironment{boxminted}
 {%
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  \RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\mintedbox}
  \begin{minted}%
 }
 {%
  \end{minted}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \noindent\colorbox{codebackground}{\makebox[\msize][l]{\usebox{\mintedbox}}}%
 }


\begin{document} 

\begin{boxminted}{c}
int main() {
  printf("hello, world");
  return 0;
}
\end{boxminted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give some explanations ? I would like to remove the background color and auto-fit the box width with my text width. I have no idea how I can adapt your code to do that. Thanks.

Comment: [Line wrapping is what I actually needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2171495).